# Getting SQL for already populated tables? PHP My Admin

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database, phpmyadmin

Using MySQL I can run the query:

SHOW CREATE TABLE employee;
And it will return the create table statement for the specified table. This is useful if you have a table already created, and want to create the same table on another database.

Is it possible to get the insert statement for an already existing set of rows, so that if a blank db with the tables created is set up, the sql can be pasted into the query box & all the tables will be populated exactly the same as the original?

Thanks

Example of data populated in the table, retrieving the sql for this.
[image]

Comment: You can export the entire database with schema and data all together or data(insert statements) and schema(create statements) separately. And in phpmyadmin has both options

Comment: yeah i know that.. the question was how to retrieve the sql for insert statements separately..

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite following; in your comment you ask about retrieving sql statements separately but my understanding of the question is that you want to be able to insert data into an already existing database (which would have the same structure). So I'm not sure what you're trying to separate; do you want each individual row as a separate INSERT statement or file?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following link for exporting DB from phpmyadmin

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204403864/export-and-import-mysql-databases